# How to query multiple rows involving a MAX?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

Assume I have a table like this:

```
column A(int)  column B(int)
       1          2
       2          6
       3          1
```

I want to write a query like this:  `SELECT A, B, MAX(B) FROM TABLE` and have it return to me:

```
1, 2, 6
2, 6, 6
3, 1, 6
```

Most databases do this.  SQLite however only returns me one row.

How can I have SQLite apply the MAX method to every row in the resultset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A, B, (SELECT MAX(B) FROM TABLE) AS MaxB
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: @Joe - Yeah, I know, "ugh" in fact